# HTML: Jinja2 JSON doesn't parse

Tags: html, jinja2

I have this JSON format which I use for jinja2, but it doesn't load with:

```
                    {% for user in data['users'] %}
                        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 mt-5">
                            <div class="card card-bordered">
                                <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="{{ user['profile_picture'] }}" alt="image">
                                <div class="card-body">

                                    <h4 class="title" style="color: #ea3c53;font-weight: bold;margin-left: 4px;">{{ user["username"] }}</h4>
                                    <div class="s-report-title d-flex justify-content-between">
                                        <p style="font-size: 12px;font-weight: 700;color: #565656;background: #ececec;letter-spacing: 0;padding: 0 9px;height: 20px;line-height: 20px;border-radius: 13px;/* margin-left: 14.6rem; */margin-bottom: 5px;">{{ user["role"] }}</p>
                                        <span style="color:#49E29D;font-size: 15px;font-weight: 600;letter-spacing: 0;/* margin-left: 11rem; */">1,500 Followers</span>
                                    </div>

                                    <h4 class="title" style="font-weight: normal;margin-left: 1px;font-size: 17px;letter-spacing: 0.4px;font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;color: #FFFFFF;">About Winteka:</h4>
                                    <p class="card-text" style="font-size: 18px;">{{ user["bio"] }}</p>
                                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" style="background: #49E29D;border: 2px solid #49E29D;">Follow</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    {% endfor %}
```

This is the JSON Object which I'm trying to work with.

```
{
   "users":[
      {
         "username":"9nematix",
         "bio":null,
         "role":"user",
         "profile_picture":null
      },
      {
         "username":"3nematix",
         "bio":null,
         "role":"user",
         "profile_picture":null
      },
      {
         "username":"6nematix",
         "bio":null,
         "role":"user",
         "profile_picture":null
      }
   ]}
```

The JSON format does work when I call it data in jinja2

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, jinja2 doesn't support - `null` in JSON format.